# I want a textbox to be disabled when a textarea has nothing written inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to have a texbox enabled only when their is text written inside a certain textarea.

I tried using the onkeydown attribute for the textarea with a method I wrote. It works when I start typing (the button is enabled), but when I delete all the text and the textarea is empty, the button is still enabled.

//This is the html code for the textbox and textarea

```
<input type="text" id="testUser" disabled="disabled" placeholder="username">
<textarea rows="15" cols="105" id="sql" onkeydown="enableUsername()">
```

//This is the Javascript method I wrote

```
function enableUsername(){
    var ele = document.getElementById("sql").value;
    //document.getElementById("sql").value=+ele.length;
    var flag = 0;
  if(ele.length>0){
    document.getElementById("testUser").disabled=false;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("testUser").disabled=true;
  }
}
```

If possible I would rather not have to use the onkeydown attribute for the textarea because I have another functionality I would like to implement later.

Comment: "I have another functionality I would like to implement later." That means what? Do you think you can only bind one function to an input event listener?

Comment: Use the "change" event which fires, when something changes. Another option is the "blur" event which fires, when the textarea loses focus.

Comment: I have a button that automatically fills the textarea with text so I. D.o.n.t want to use key down

Comment: It is also no problem to use the event more than once. (event bubbling).

Comment: Use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Comment: But it will still be enabled when I hit backspace. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No JavaScript events are triggered if you fill in the input with JavaScript. You need to trigger the event manually when you make the change. The event listeners trigger only when the user alters it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working snippet below -

```js
var txtarea = document.getElementById('sql');
var username = document.getElementById('testUser');

function enableUsername() {
  if (txtarea.value.length > 0) {
    username.disabled = false;
  } else {
    username.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="testUser" disabled="true" placeholder="username" />
<textarea rows="15" cols="105" id="sql" onkeydown="enableUsername()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `onkeydown` by `onkeyup`.

```
<input type="text" id="testUser" disabled="disabled" placeholder="username">
<textarea rows="15" cols="105" id="sql"></textarea>
```

```
var ele = document.getElementById("sql");

function enableUsername() {
  var flag = 0;

  if (ele.value.length > 0){
    document.getElementById("testUser").disabled=false;
  } else{
    document.getElementById("testUser").disabled=true;
  }
}
ele.addEventListener("keyup", enableUsername, false);
```